# Tener varios proyectos Laravel Sail en Docker

Tags: laravel, docker, nginx, puertos

¿Cómo manejar correctamente los puertos de varias imagenes dentro de los contenedores Docker para servir aplicaciones y que no entren en conflicto con otros contenedores?

Actualmente estoy teniendo problemas para poder crear más de una aplicación en Docker. En Valet era muy sencillo pero aqui en Windows no me resulta tan sencillo. No conozco bien las causas pero sé que los puertos pueden interferir, por lo que se deben especificar puertos distintos.

Abajo muestro una manera que he intentado introducir una nueva ubicación para acceder a "app2"

```
location ^~ /app2 {
    alias /var/www/html/app2/public;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @app2;

    location ~ \.php {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    }
}

location @app2{
    rewrite /app2/(.*)$ /app2/index.php?/$1 last;
}
```

Cuando quiero acceder a la "app2", como "localhost/app2" me dice "File not found," ¿lo estoy haciendo bien?

Otra cosa que he intentado es hacer un "proxy-manager" con Nginx, lo saqué de este tutorial: https://blog.devgenius.io/multi-laravel-sail-sites-with-custom-domain-e13c07d9dd0c

Al querer realizar este proxy manager, me sale 403 forbidden. Cuando quiero correr el docker usando el comando `./vendor/bin/sail up` pero me dice que un puerto está en uso.

Lo que necesito es poder manejar varias imagenes sin repetir los puertos pero esto parece imposible. Quiero poder tener varias aplicaciones funcionando. No estoy tratando de correr una API, simplemente quiero tener proyectos separados y que cada uno funcione.

Esta es mi configuración actual en "etc/nginx/sites-available/default".

```
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
# http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
#
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        # SSL configuration
        #
        # listen 443 ssl default_server;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #
        # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/html/sickofmetal/public;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name localhost;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
                # proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
                # proxy_http_version 1.1;
                # proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                # proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                # proxy_set_header Host $host;
                # proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
                deny all;
        }
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com

# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#       listen 80;
#       listen [::]:80;
#
#       server_name example.com;
#
#       root /var/www/example.com;
#       index index.html;
#
#       location / {
#               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#       }
#}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo resolví haciendo un archivo conf para cada aplicación. La única variante es el puerto que se utiliza en el "listen" y la ruta hacia el proyecto.

Entonces tengo dos archivos de configuración para cada aplicación con su "symlink" en la carpeta `sites-enabled`

```
    listen 82; // se específica un puerto diferente
    listen [::]:82; // aquí también
    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www/html/app2/public; // la ruta al proyecto

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Después se crea un symlink:

```
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/app2.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
```

Se revisa que no haya errores en la configuración: `nginx -t`

Se resetea nginx: `systemctl restart nginx`

Y se accede: `localhost:82`

Espero sirva de algo.